# ORA-24247 Oracle ACLs on UTL_HTTP on Linux

Tags: linux, oracle, http, ora-24247

I have created an ACL to access a web server from a Oracle XE 11GR2 user on Windows, and using UTL_HTTP.request() works fine.
I have created the same ACL in an Oracle Enterprise 11GR2 DB user on a Linux Redhat server, but the command UTL_HTTP.request() gives the classical error 24247 - network access denied by ACL.
I have checked and rechecked the ACLs definitions and are identical in boths machines.
All the Windows, Linux and remote host computers are on the same network.
I tested curl from the Linux machine to the remote server and worked OK.
Running utl_http.request() in Linux with sys user and worked OK.
No proxys.

So 2 questions:

Is the sys user not affected by the ACL rules?

Is something to be done in Linux server not documented, to make this work?.

I read the post where the OID was the problem, but no idea how to check that.

Any tip what to do would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please see **"How to configure Access Control List"** at:

http://www.oracleflash.com/36/Oracle-11g-Access-Control-List-for-External-Network-Services.html

Above the "How to configure Access Control List", provides an explanation of why you could be receiving the error. It also may be because Oracle is installed on the Windows machine as SYSTEM or similar, either way, creating the ACL via that method should do the job.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I have configured correctly the ACL in both Linux and Windows. I do not understand what you mean by SYSTEM. It is supposed that you should indicate the user or role to give permissions. I think the problem is not in the DB side, but in some Linux variable that the UTL_HTTP looks for before failing, like http_proxy and something like this I read in many of the articles in internet related with this error.

Comment: Are you using https - anything involving site certificates?

Comment: No, just http. The remote server then connects to an external web service using https.